# How to link an audio mp3 file created on soundcloud to your Youtube account

Tags: streaming, audio

i want create a sound file on soundcloud and bring it to my youtube account.  How do i achieve this?

Comment: Download it from SoundCloud, add as the sound track to a video, upload it to Youtube.  Is there more to your question than this?  Are you simply asking how to add it as the sound track to a video?

Comment: You can link it in the description or if you are a youtube partner you can embed links in your video as annotations.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to reupload the file to Youtube.

Convert the audio file (preferably your original, uncompressed file) to video with `avconv -loop 1 -i cover.jpg -i original-track.wav -tune stillimage -r 1 -s 1280x720 -c:a flac -shortest -v error out-video.ogv` (where cover.jpg is the still image you want to use for the video) or using a media converter like [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/), and upload it to your youtube account.

You can place a link to the soundcloud page in your video description.